# How to put the Date in the hidden field selected from the date picker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a date picker for text field which puts in format of 5-MAY-2011 .On close of this date picker i need to write to hidden field 
or text field in this format 5/5/2011

```
$( '#txt_field').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', onClose: function() {$( '#hiddenfield').attr('value' ,$( '#txt_field').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy'}) )}});
```

when i do this iam getting object object in the hidden field

Comment: Isn't the return value of the .datepicker call the jQuery object for the datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#txt_field').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', 
onClose: function() {
    var date = new Date($(this).val());
    if (date) {
        var formattedDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + 
                            date.getDate() + "/" + 
                            date.getFullYear();
        $('#hiddenfield').val(formattedDate);
    }
}
});
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rSEnB/

Comment: Ariel: Notworking as Expected .Please take a look at this  link http://jsfiddle.net/RMHJJ/19/ . If we select 5th may it is giving 4/4/2011 which should be 5/5/2011

Comment: use this to get date instead "var date = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );" - I have edited the answer accordingly.